# Move a specific widget to another container via XML

Tags: magento2, xml

I want to move a specific widget, lets name it `demoWidget` to the top container, when it is on a site.

How can I achieve this?

I've thought about this solution, but have no idea how to do it:

- give the widget a specific name in CMS page (like `name="demoWidget"`)
- on CMS page XML tab, use `<move>`in order to move `name="demoWidget"`
- - If `name="demoWidget"` is not there, will there be an error and if so how can I set conditions correctly?

Comment: did you found any way ?